# Update view on server side event in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to build web-based chat using ASP.NET MVC as a backend and S22.Xmpp library for chat functionality. The problem is that ***receive*** message handler is on the server side, however updating view is needed on client. I believe it is a simple situation for front-end guys, but I am not one of them.

How to update view on receiveing new message from other client in chat? I assume it is needed to use AJAX. Please guide me.

```
public class ChatController : Controller
    {
        public ChatController()
        {
            ChatEngine.Instance.OnMessageReceived = MessageReceived;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handler on message received
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void MessageReceived(S22.Xmpp.Im.MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            // we can do only server side updates, but can't to manipulate View here
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");  // this doesn't work
        }
```

Comment: You will need to create a callback on server side to update. Try taking a look at signalr

Comment: Handler already added as you can see in code OnMessageReceived. SignalR is not an option, i am using XMPP.

Comment: I don't know this library. But on event you can redirect view so somehow you have to push this data to receiver. This instance will called by center so there is no meaning trying to redirect view for receiver on this instance.

Comment: And what makes you think you can't use SignalR alongside XMPP? SignalR is an alternative to plain AJAX, it is not an alternative to XMPP.

Comment: Finally I choose SignalR as a chat engine, have used xmpp because of experienced with.